# run cts -c android.permission2.cts.ProtectedBroadcastsTest

Tags: permissions, cts

```
run cts -c android.permission2.cts.ProtectedBroadcastsTest
```

The test is failed.

Log:

```
   android.permission2.cts.ProtectedBroadcastsTest#testSendProtectedBroadcasts FAIL 
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected security exception broadcasting action: com.android.server.WifiManager.action.START_SCAN
at android.permission2.cts.ProtectedBroadcastsTest.testSendProtectedBroadcasts(ProtectedBroadcastsTest.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

please check this commit.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b8da0376f2d50fdb2ee58deacc6d2041689e36d1%5E!/

This is framework behavior change.